# Does this painting depict the Alps or Rockies?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, mountains, alps, canadian-rockies

This painting is oil, old and I've been searching for the location. It would help if this mountain range could be sourced, I could then figure out who the artist might be.

[image]

Comment: Not much help, but the painting reminds me of one I’ve seen in the Scottish National Gallery.

Comment: Are you sure it's even a real mountain and not fictional?  It could be in many, many places.

Comment: I do not remember red mountains on Alps (also the snowy one is reddish). Geologically Alps were ocean bed (so mostly non volcanic)

Comment: Doing a reverse image search of the entire painting on google might give some good results/starting points

Answer (score 13):

This painting can be found online (and a friend of mine did) and [here is a link](https://fineartamerica.com/featured/herbst-am-silsersee-john-lyes.html).

That site mentions the picture to be by an unknown artist but the title to the picture: "Herbst Am Silsersee".

Herbst means autumn (or fall,) Silsersee translates to Lake Sils, and that has a [Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Sils) And that lake is located in Switzerland and that makes it the Alps rather than the Rockies.

Comment: If "Silbersee" is the specifically fictional lake in the so-named Karl May novels it would probably depict the Rockies. The art style does remind me of the old pocket book covers in my cupboard at my parents home. Whoops, you write "Silsersee" - misread that.

Comment: @JakeDot, see the Wikipedia page for Silbersee, plenty of German, Swiss and Austrian places to choose from. But Silsersee has only one location.

Comment: Even the page you linked to has it in the description: "HERBST AM SILSERSEE in the Swiss Alps"